# Teradata create volatile doesn't work on JDBC

Tags: sql, jdbc, teradata, teradatasql

When running the following Python code and SQL query on a Teradata Vantage Express server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import teradatasql

query = """CREATE VOLATILE TABLE target_table AS (
    select * FROM MY_DB.MY_TABLE
  )
    WITH DATA ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
SELECT * FROM target_table;"""

con = teradatasql.connect(host="localhost", user="dbc", password="dbc")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(query)
```

I get the following error:

`teradatasql.OperationalError: [Version 17.20.0.7] [Session 2988] [Teradata Database] [Error 3932] Only an ET or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement.`

However, when using bteq (Teradata's CLIv2 db connector), and running the same query it works like a charm and doesn't throw any error:

```
 BTEQ -- Enter your SQL request or BTEQ command:
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE target_table AS (
    select * FROM MY_DB.MY_TABLE
  )
    WITH DATA ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

CREATE VOLATILE TABLE target_table AS (
    select * FROM MY_DB.MY_TABLE
  )
    WITH DATA ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

 *** Table has been created.
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.


 BTEQ -- Enter your SQL request or BTEQ command:
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM target_table;

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM target_table;

 *** Query completed. One row found. 9 columns returned.
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

customer_id     customer_token                customer_branch customer_num
-------------- ------------------------------ --------------- ------------
          8585      452004                                 83       808038

 BTEQ -- Enter your SQL request or BTEQ command:
```

Any idea?

Note that no useful Google entries were found for either Python based JDBC drivers (e.g. teradatasql) or Node.js based drivers.

Comment: This appears to be an exact duplicate of another question that was answered and then deleted. The issue is that the “query” variable has 2 SQL statements in it. You need to alter this so that there is only a single SQL statement in the string being passed to the execute statement

Comment: @NickW I can't, the query comes from the user and I'm using off-the-shelf analytics engines that have JDBC connectors under the hood. Again, the same queries work on Teradata SQL Assistant or bteq (which uses CLIv2). The goal is to allow seamless transition from Teradata SQL Assistant / bteq into our analytics engine, without asking the user to apply any changes to his/hers queries.

Comment: I think you need to set your session mode to Teradata, not ansi.  Think as part of your connection string you need `"tmode":"TERA"`. You can reproduce this behavior in bteq if you use `.SET SESSION TRANSACTION ANSI;` before you log in.

Answer (score 1):

In the bteq examples you’ve given there are individual queries being executed; each query is separated by a “;”. However, in the Python code you have combined 2 queries into a single string and are trying to execute that string as a single query - which won’t work.

You need to write the Python code to run each query separately, in the same way that the bteq code does. For example:

```
query = """CREATE VOLATILE TABLE target_table AS (
    select * FROM MY_DB.MY_TABLE
  )
    WITH DATA ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;”””

con = teradatasql.connect(host="localhost", user="dbc", password="dbc")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(query)

query = “””SELECT * FROM target_table;"""
cur.execute(query)
```

Comment: I understand. So does bteq also apply string splitting by ; (semicolon) behind the scenes before actually executing it via the query engine?

Comment: BTEQ will execute the individual statements you pass to it. Statements are separated by semicolons

Comment: BTEQ submits a request when no new command starts after a semicolon on the same line. This allows combining multiple statements into one request as a MSR = Multi-Statement Request (similar to GO on SQL Server command line). In SQL Assistant it's F9 vs F5.